# Iterating through expensive async function - memory constraints, recursion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, out-of-memory

I'm having some issues with what I think is a basic problem regarding use of Promises in my node.JS server side application - unfortunately I can't see how to resolve it despite seeing other similar questions (I think).

Basically my issue is this:
I am trying to retrieve some external data and then process it. There is a lot of data so I have to retrieve it page by page. Additionally given the size of the data, my server cannot execute multiple calls/processes at once as I run out of memory and the server crashes. I don't know until execution time how many pages I have to retrieve to get all the data.

I have tried executing a forEach loop with an array of the number of pages however this clearly doesn't work. e.g.:

```
pages = [1,2,3,4];
pages.forEach( function(pageNumber){
  veryMemoryExpensiveFunctionRetrievingAndProcessingPage(pageNumber).then(
// handle the results);
})
```

(the behaviour here is that all functions execute synchronously and the server runs out of memory).

I'm pretty stuck here - I know I need to execute that function multiple times synchronously but dont know where to start with doing so! I've also attempted recursion however this again causes out of memory as each call adds to the stack.

Comment: Sounds like you need to work on optimizing your server side solution instead of client side.

Comment: Hi apologies - I should have clarified that this is a node.js server side application - I am retrieving data from an external service, modifying it and inserting it into my own DB. I can only retrieve it paginated plus my own server seems to be only able to hold a certain number of pages in memory without crashing. Hence I want to force sequential processing of pages on my own server side

Comment: @JDeane First of all: http://www.codexpedia.com/javascript/increasing-the-memory-limit-in-node-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to obtain a promise for each page when the previous one completes, rather than all at once. i.e

```
function fetchAndProcessPages(i, handlePage) {
    retrievePage(pages[i]).then(page => {
        handlePage(page);
        if (i+1 < pages.length) fetchAndProcessPages(i+1, handlePage);
    });
}
fetchAndProcessPages(0, page => console.log(page));
```

Comment: This is great - thanks! Seems obvious now but I guess thats always the case!